# File I/O Model; Combining Modes & Having File Parameters Defined Outside of Function: Cause a Crash

Tags: file, io, lua

```
local file_path = "Test.lua"
local file = io.open(file_path, "r")
local content = file:read("*a")
local file = io.open(file_path, "w")
function replace(string_id, value)
    local string_id_search = tostring(string_id)
    local string_id_reconfiguration = tostring(value)
    local output = string.gsub(content, string_id_search, string_id_reconfiguration)
    file:write(output) -- Says this is a closed file, why?
    file:close()
end
```

This is currently my code . I have this repeated in a few other functions and I want to optimize it. So I want to first take out the first 3 local variables of the function and make the entire script have them as locals. Second, I want to combine the local file variable so it's just 1.

Problem 1) If I take the first 3 local variables out, it crashes saying the `file:write(output)` line is trying to write a closed file.

Problem 2) If I make the file mode `"rw"` or `"wr"` instead, it crashes as well. I tried all the other modes and got these results...

```
r does nothing (doesn't write the needed data, obviously)
w nukes all the data in the file (and writes nothing)
a does nothing
r+ does nothing
w+ nukes everything
a+ does nothing
```

Am I doing something wrong with the modes, or can they just not be combined?

Comment: It is that version. I don't understand what you mean that version. If I pull out the first 3 and run the script, it crashes. I don't know what you want (I will edit the OP to show what I mean). BTW did you delete the past comments?

Comment: You're describing a problem occurring inside the function, but this is impossible because the function is never called. In other words, you didn't provide all the relevant code. The problem may be in the code you didn't provided.

Comment: Another thing: a function should preferably do one thing only, and should be "self contained" if possible. Your function pokes at variables outside of it and it'd be hard for the programmer to ensure the function is called only when these outside variables are in the proper state.

Comment: The file is automatically loaded up upon the interpreter being opened (the interpreter is a game's engine). So it's running the script initially or initializing it (I would think). I want to use the variables outside the function because other functions use those same variables and rather then repeat them...I figured ok...let's make them local variables that can be used in the entire script. Unless I am doing it wrong.